# Apache beam on google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run a job on Google Cloud Dataflow but can't get the deployment to work. The job runs fine using DirectRunner but as soon as I switch over to dataflow-runner I get the following exception:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Runner was specified and the DirectRunner was not found on the classpath.
Specify a runner by either:
    Explicitly specifying a runner by providing the 'runner' property
    Adding the DirectRunner to the classpath
    Calling 'PipelineOptions.setRunner(PipelineRunner)' directly
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions$DirectRunner.create(PipelineOptions.java:286)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions$DirectRunner.create(PipelineOptions.java:276)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:575)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:516)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:155)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsValidator.validate(PipelineOptionsValidator.java:70)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:44)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:138)
        at my.package.SalesTransactions.main(SalesTransactions.java:218)
```

My command to run:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.package.SalesTransactions -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner --project=my-project --tempLocation=gs://my-project/tmp" -Pdataflow-runner
```

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml or confirm that you have added a dependency on the Dataflow runner?

Comment: I've added a pom.xml extract showing the maven profile used.

Answer (score 2):

Found my mistake. When switching over from DirectRunner to DataFlowRunner I had to add the dependency in my pom.xml instead of just having it as a profile runtime dependency.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```